# return type with the same property names

Tags: typescript, generics

I want a function to return a type that has the same property names as a generic type parameter type.

I'v tried:

```
function getObjectInfo<T>(obj: T): { [key: keyof T]: any; }  {
    const info = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(propertyName => {
        info[propertyName] = { /* some info object */ };
    });
    return info;
}
```

and

```
function getObjectInfo<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T): { [key: K]: any; }  {
    const info = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(propertyName => {
        info[propertyName] = { /* some info object */ };
    });
    return info;
}
```

but get the following error

> An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

update:

Also tried:

```
function getObjectInfo<T extends { [key: string]: any }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T): { [key: K]: any; }  {
    const info = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(propertyName => {
        info[propertyName] = { /* some info object */ };
    });
    return info;
}
```

so K is not a union type but still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error says, you might consider using a mapped object to do this. A mapped object would use the syntax `[key in keyof T]` instead of `[key: keyof T]`, and will map those keys to whatever type you specify (in your case, `any`).

Here's what that would look like for your snippet. The only change is the return type:

```
function getObjectInfo<T>(obj: T): { [key in keyof T]: any; } {
    const info = {};
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(propertyName => {
        info[propertyName] = { /* some info object */ };
    });
    return info;
}

const x = getObjectInfo({foo: "bar"}); // x has type {foo: any}
```

---

Additionally, you can use the built in `Record` type as another solution to this. The `Record` type accepts two generic arguments. The first is a string union representing the keys of the record, and the second is the type they map to. So the above return type could also be replaced with `Record<keyof T, any>` for the same result.

Comment: Awesome I didn't know what "consider using a mapped object to do this" meant, I guess that should have been the question.